Capture Adobe Analytics for the HTML content download via Ajax calls?
I am currently developing a single-page application that loads additional HTML content through Ajax calls based on user interactions. I am interested in tracking analytics through Adobe Analytics to determine how many times these HTML pages are loaded by all users.
Can any one provide some guidance on how I can achieve this?
Thank you for your time and assistance.
